# How to read the content from the second line onwards on a .txt file on C

Tags: arrays, c, file

I need help to read the numbers of a .txt file and put them in an array. But only from the second line onwards. I'm stuck and don't know where to go from the code that i built.

Example of the .txt file:
10 20
45000000
48000000
56000000

```
#define MAX 50
int main (void){
    FILE *file;
    int primNum;
    int secNum;
    int listOfNumers[50];
    int numberOfLines = MAX;
    int i = 0;

    file = fopen("file.txt", "rt");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d %d\n", &primNum, &secNum);

    printf("\n1st Number: %d",primNum);
    printf("\n2nd Number: %d",secNum);

    printf("List of Numbers");

    for(i=0;i<numberOfLines;i++){
        //Count the number from the second line onwards
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Skip the first line, read the second onwards and put each number in the array listOfNumers.

Comment: `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); /* ignore first line */ while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) { if (process(buf)) break; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a loop to keep reading `int`s from `file` and populate the `listOfNumers` array until reading an `int` fails.

Since you don't know how many `int`s there are in the file, you could also allocate the memory dynamically. Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "rt");
    if(file == NULL) {
        perror("file.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    int primNum;
    int secNum;
    if(fscanf(file, "%d %d", &primNum, &secNum) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed reading primNum and secNum\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned numberOfLines = 0;

    // allocate space for one `int`
    int* listOfNumers = malloc((numberOfLines + 1) * sizeof *listOfNumers);
    // the above could just be:
    // int* listOfNumers = malloc(sizeof *listOfNumers);

    while(fscanf(file, "%d", listOfNumers + numberOfLines) == 1) {
        ++numberOfLines;
        // increase the allocated space by the sizeof 1 int
        int* np = realloc(listOfNumers, (numberOfLines + 1) * sizeof *np);
        if(np == NULL) break; // if allocating more space failed, break out
        listOfNumers = np;    // save the new pointer
    }
    fclose(file);

    puts("List of Numbers:");
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", listOfNumers[i]);
    }

    free(listOfNumers); // free the dynamically allocated space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this; if you know the size of the first line, you should be able to use `fseek` to move the position of the file than use `getline` to get each line of the file:

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

The `whence` parameter  can be:

- `SEEK_SET` : the Beginning
- `SEEK_CUR` : the current position
- `SEEK_END` : the End

The other option would to encapsulate the entire file read in a while loop:

```
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;
    int counter = 0;

    while((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, file)) != -1){
        if counter == 0{
            sscanf(line, "%d %d\n", &primNum, &secNum);
        }else{
            //Process your line
        }
        counter++; //This would give you your total line length
    }
```

Comment: `getline` is not a standard C function though. You also need to `free` each `line` in the loop and after the loop.

Comment: Should still be part of stdio.h if he is compiling for modern linux.

You should free line at the end regardless of the solutions he is going for, I was just trying to provide a quick example to follow.     That being said, I believe getline provides the null character, so if you use a char array instead you would only need to free at the end.

Comment: The `getline()` function was a GNU extension that has been a part of POSIX for quite a while.  It is not standard C, but it is standardized and widely available.  Using `fgets()` would work well for the sample data, and that is standard C.